# How to model event responses into dataset for classifier

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-modeling

I have large dataset of events reported during device sessions. Each session contain many events defined by event_id and event_type and class label. How can I model such data into dataset for classification problem?

TL;DR; How would I convert list of attributes (timestamp, device_id, event_type, event_id, label) into dataset for classification?

Answer (score -1):

> Use Lable Encoder to convert it into  Binary
>   ex:

```
#converting into binary
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
lb=LabelEncoder()
df["column"]=lb.fit_transform(df["column"])
```

Comment: My question is not how to convert discrete variables into continuous but rather how to model event list aka DataFrame into a data format for predictive classifier model